# Use one layout and change strings programatically in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Okay, I want to use one layout and change my strings programatically using the strings.xml.

I have 40 questions and always 4 answers (they are static).

so my idea would be something like:

```
while i < 40:
 set question to question[i]
 on answer click: i++
```

How can I fetch the strings dynamically. I always used `getResources().getText(R.string.example)`.

Can I just do something like:

```
String dynamic = "R.string.example" + i;
getResources().getText(dynamic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could save the answers and the questions in an array in strings.xml (or somewhere else), or maybe some more arrays if you want that. So you can then load the array like you do now with getResources(), but with [getStringArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray%28int%29)
And if you have an array, you can just dynamically get the right answer/question or whatever you want to do with it.

In strings.xml (or another xml):

```
<string-array name="months_array">
    <item>Jan</item>
    <item>Feb</item>
    <item>Mar</item>
    <item>Apr</item>
    <item>May</item>
    <item>Jun</item>
    <item>Jul</item>
    <item>Aug</item>
    <item>Sep</item>
    <item>Oct</item>
    <item>Nov</item>
    <item>Dec</item>
</string-array>
```

In your code:

```
String[] months = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.months_array);
```

Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Okay, I want to use one layout and change my strings programatically
> using the strings.xml.

That is the way to go if you don't need any animation at all.

> Can I just do something like:
>
> String dynamic = "R.string.example" + i;
>
> getResources().getText(dynamic)

Use the [Resources.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
int textId = getResources().getIdentifier("example" + i, "string", getPackageName());
getResources().getText(textId);
```

But, as `ndsmyter` already said, you may want to look at having all the questions and answers in 5 different arrays(1 for the question text and 4 for the 4 answers). You'll then load this array only once at startup and then simple use the `i` to get all the data from the 5 arrays in one hit.